# asp.net System.IO.IOException

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to programatically build a list of files in a folder, with certain attributes like file size and modified date.

I can return the file name, but any other attribute throws an error:  System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

What am I missing here?

```
    private void BuildDocList()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(FilePath));

        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            var file = new FileInfo(FilePath + f);
            var fileItem = new ListItem();

            // this line works fine
            fileItem.Text = file.Name.Split('.')[0] + ", ";


            // this line causes the runtime error
            fileItem.Text = file.CreationTime.ToShortDateString();

            FileList.Items.Add(fileItem);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the wrong filename for the `FileInfo` - you're using the unmapped path. You should use something like this:

```
string directory = Server.MapPath(FilePath);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

foreach (string f in files)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(directory, f));
    // Now the properties should work.
```